# Moving sublayout that contains another sublayout from one placeholder to another

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have an issue in the Page Editor where i have created a sublayout in a placeholder, and add another sublayout inside that sublayout (nested sublayout).
And when i moved the parent sublayout to another placeholder (still using Page Editor), I am only moving the parent sublayout, but not the child sublayout. The child sublayout still pointing to the old placeholder, while the parent sublayout pointing to the new placeholder. 
Is there any way to move both the parent sublayout and child sublayout from one placeholder to another using the Page Editor without having to go to the Presentation Layout in the Content Editor ? 


Kind regards,

Adi

Comment: Just a hint for possible close voters: SiteCore is a high-end CMS and these type of questions can only be asked by or are useful for developers, not for normal users. Migration to Superuser.com is not correct. See also [this MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566/how-to-report-invalid-downvotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Page Editor. On saving of the renderings field, Sitecore does not crawl through nested sublayouts in the previous renderings to find any children that need to be updated.

You could customize the pipelines to do this search and update the renderings XML  yourself. Alternatively, some of the Sitecore development accelerators that are available for purchase already have this fix in it.